# Why does Airflow claim SQLite is the default backend when it seems to be Postgres?

Tags: airflow

I'm running Airflow 2.2.1 on Docker via the [provided official image](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow). Now, [the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/production-deployment.html) says that:

> Airflow comes with an SQLite backend by default. This allows the user to run Airflow without any external database. However, such a setup is meant to be used for testing purposes only; running the default setup in production can lead to data loss in multiple scenarios. If you want to run production-grade Airflow, make sure you configure the backend to be an external database such as PostgreSQL or MySQL.

However, the [docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) given in the documentation (see [Running Airflow in Docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml)) makes no mention of SQLite. In fact, it has defines (among other things):

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
```

So now I'm confused. Why does the documentation claim SQLite is the default backend? Is the default backend not a Postgres database? Be as it may, should I be happy using the Postgres database provided here for production use, or should I set up my own custom db as a backend as the docs suggest (see [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html))? In fact, I don't quite even understand how the default backend is a Postgres DB - does this also run inside a separate container?

Comment: The default configuration is SQLite, however, when you run it with using the given docker-compose, this config is overriden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airflow (without the docker-compose file or Helm Chart) uses SQLite by default.

However, the official [docker-compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) creates a Postgres container and uses that so that you can run tasks in parallel.

Similarly, the [official Helm Chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/quick-start.html) also creates a Postgres service for quick testing.

However, for the Production use case you should not use a Database running inside a container as containers are most popularly used for ephemeral storage/tasks. Hence for Production, you should use a managed Database like Cloud SQL (on GCP). Details: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#database

Comment: Excellent, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!